Sampling isoclinic rotations?
I'm interested in sampling isoclinic rotations  randomly in $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $n$ is even.
This answer from user1551 suggests that for $n=4$, this space is 2-dimensional. What a good way to define a uniform measure over this 2-dimensional space, and how would I sample from it?

What does "uniform" mean? You can sample isoclinic rotations as exponentials of sums of commuting bivectors, but is that "uniform"?

The isoclinic rotations in $4$-dimensions form two subgroups each of dimension $3$ which intersect with each other in ${I,-I}$. Your other question doesn't look like it is about isoclinic rotations to me.
